# What is the SQL Query To Find in MySQL DB Table without considering the accented letters?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Like the Title.

What is the SQL Query To Find in MySQL DB Table without considering the accented letters?

So, if I search "abcdè" I find "abcde"

Comment: Do you want to be able to use an index for this search?

Comment: If you want the accented letter to be treated the same as its non-accented counterpart, you need to have appropriate collation for your table. That way MySQL will treat those 2 letters (or more) as if they were the same one. If there isn't the appropriate collation that satisfies your needs, you'll have to create your own. Data available at MySQL's docs.

Comment: If your collation is binary, it will not. If it is not a binary collation (like `latin1_general_ci` or `utf_general_ci`), it will apply the collation's rules. Which usually does what you want exactly, treating accented letters as non-accented ones (depending on the charset that yout table and column uses).

Answer (score 1):

By default utf8 strings ignore accents as they use the utf8_general_ci collation.

If you're not using utf8 (and why not?) Then you probably want to use the COLLATE command:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html

```
 SELECT *
 FROM t1
 WHERE _latin1 'Müller' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci = k;

 SELECT *
 FROM t1
 WHERE k LIKE _latin1 'Müller' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;
```

Also, you can apparently use the 'SET NAMES' command to alter the comparisons:

[MySQL diacritic insensitive search (spanish accents)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304464/mysql-diacritic-insensitive-search-spanish-accents)

Answer (score 0):

Collation is the set of rules your DB is using to compare values. "all" you have to do is choose the right collation for your application. That said, @Danack57 above already gave you that piece of information.

Comment: And how can i find which particular collation offers what *i* need? (which in my case should also disregard diacritics, not merely accents. I doubt UTF8 matches ç and c...)

Comment: Yeah, i thought that would be required... And if none of them is suitable? :-s

Comment: I mean, collations are useful for sorting, but the question is about seeking strings, trying to allow for "variants" of letters to be seen as equal... Can collations do that?