# MySQL: Why can I search some accent marks but not others?

Tags: mysql, collation

I am using MySQL 8 and the dataset contains these 3 latin accent characters `í ñ é`.  So the thing I am trying to figure out is why am I able to search  `í é`, but not `ñ` when using the non-accented version of the character.  What do I need to do so I can search all those characters by using the non-accent version?

My Collation on the DB/Table/Column is `utf8mb4_spanish_ci` and Character Set is `utf8mb4`.

[image]

Comment: Interesting question. This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304464/mysql-diacritic-insensitive-search-spanish-accents

Comment: Please provide `SELECT HEX(place) FROM baptism WHERE ...` so I can see the hex encoding of those letters.  Also provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE baptism` so we can tell what collation is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the reason might be because `ñ` is not exactly `n`.

*"The character “ñ” is a precomposed character because it is treated as an individual Unicode character and has a Unicode code point of U+00F1. Technically, this character can be decomposed into an equivalent string of a base character “n” (U+006E) and a combining tilde “~” (U+0303)."*
[Reference](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2274038&seqNum=9#:%7E:text=Precomposed%20Diacritics&text=The%20character%20%E2%80%9C%C3%B1%E2%80%9D%20is%20a,%E2%80%9D%20(U%2B0303).)

There is a way to make `ñ` recognizable as `n` by adding `COLLATE` in the query, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM baptism WHERE place LIKE '%n%' COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

[Try here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5d4c71a300b70299b17e15a789be8005)