# MySQL diacritic insensitive FULLTEXT search

Tags: mysql, sql, search, full-text-search, diacritics

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3304596/1422096), I have used the MySQL command

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

hoping that all these 4 cases of [MySQL FULLTEXT search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) would work :

- If `text = 'lápiz'`,

  1) `SELECT id, text FROM mytable WHERE MATCH (text) AGAINST ('lapiz' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)` should work

  2) `SELECT id, text FROM mytable WHERE MATCH (text) AGAINST ('lápiz' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)` should work
- If `text = 'lapiz'`,

  3) `SELECT id, text FROM mytable WHERE MATCH (text) AGAINST ('lapiz' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)` should work

  4) `SELECT id, text FROM mytable WHERE MATCH (text) AGAINST ('lápiz' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)` should work

Strangely, 1) and 2) **don't work** (No result found!), but 3) and 4) **work** (`lapiz` is found).

**How to have a really diacritic insensitive MySQL Full-Text search?**

**How do the [collations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-general.html) work with MySQL Full-Text search feature?**

*PS: this is not a duplicate of the previously linked question, nor of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584557/diacritic-insensitive-mysql-search). The difference seems to be linked with the use of Full-Text search MATCH(...) AGAINST (...) instead of LIKE.*

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Comment: @IvanCachicatari : I have `5.1.73-1.1+squeeze+build0+1-log`. The problem is solved since I deleted the whole DB, and started a new one with `SET NAMES utf8;` everywhere before each DB writing action... There is a last thing however : I would like then when searching for `lápiz`,  the results are given by relevance, i.e. results with `lápiz` (same diacritics) should be given **before** results with diacritics omitted (such as `lapiz`), and before results with wrong diacritics (such as `lâpïz`). How to sort by relevance?